# Pause html video after slide change, slick carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using slick carousel for a html video slider. I'm trying to pause the videos after slide is changed. The code is working only if I play the video, if the video is not played and I change the slide when I get back to that slide I can't play the video anymore. This is the part of code I am using:

```
$( '.slider' ).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    var current = $(slick.$slides[currentSlide]);
    current.html(current.html());
  });
```

Comment: Where is the video part?

Comment: I figure it out a working solution in the meantime, I posted below, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I figure it out a working solution in the meantime:

```
  $( '.slider' ).on('beforeChange', function(event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide){
    $("video").each(function(){
      this.pause();
    });
  });
```